# Many to Many relationship even when using Link table

Tags: sql, database, entity-relationship

I'm making a database where I need to create a relationship between 'Modules' and 'Degree' - basically the modules make up the degree - such like: 
Module CS 1 is part of Computer Science
Module CS 2 is part of Computer Science
Module PHIL 1 is part of Philosophy
etc.

My table format is as so: 
Modules -> Form  -> Degree

Modules contains Module Name, and Module ID (PK)

Form contains Module ID and Degree ID (both FK)

Degree contains Degree Name and Degree ID (PK)

I appear to have the issue that regardless, there will be a many-to-many relationship, as there will be multiple Module ID's which correlate to one Degree ID.

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would not be a many-to-many relationship, in fact, that is the entire purposes of the "bridge" table Form.

See the picture below. In the basic ER Diagram (Entity Relationship Diagram, you can read about them [here](https://www.w3schools.in/dbms/er-model/)), you can see the following:

- There is a **ONE-TO-MANY** relationship between Module and Form 
  (i.e., ONE Module ID can appear MANY TIMES in the Form Table, but that Module ID will only appear ONE time in the Module table)
- There is a **ONE-TO-MANY** relationship between Form and Degree
  (i.e., ONE Degree ID can appear MANY TIMES in the Form Table, but that Degree ID will only appear ONE time in the Degree table)

Your architecture and usage of a bridge table is indeed one way to eliminate a many-to-many relationship, good job.

[image]

Comment: So my lecturer was wrong!! I appreciate your articulate and helpful feedback - the diagram is really helpful in visualising how these tables work.

Comment: Not a problem. Technically, in this schema, Modules and Degree are not even "Related" - they don't join to each other, strictly through Form, so there is no way they can be many-to-many :) Good luck!~